# Is the verbosity really worth it when passing read only vector in function? const vector<const string>&

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the verbosity really worth it when passing read only vector in function?

```
const vector<const string>&
```

I usually have

```
const vector<string>&
```

which is already verbose enough. Now I see some people use the first verbose version
and I wonder is it worth it?

Comment: `std::vector<const anything>` doesn't even compile. Where did you see that version?

Comment: actually you can create vector<const string> try it. I use C++11.

Comment: I tried it. Actually I tried it a few days ago, and again just before you posted your comment. Here's mine: http://ideone.com/Pfk49S

Comment: @user3111311 1) depends on the compiler 2) if you can, you cant modify it in any way

Comment: 'Verbosity' has practically zero cost. 'Read-only' has major benefits. This doesn't appear to be a real question.

Comment: That is strange it works in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @EJP Excessive verbosity has costs too. Even if you don't believe it necessarily impacts the engineers, it does annoy many of them ;-)

Comment: @user3111311 (Bad) luck on your part, I guess. The standard doesn't allow it, as the [element type must be copy assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @delnan That's a benefit, not a cost :-)

Comment: It is worthy as void fn (const int) and as useless a const int fn()

Comment: @delnan thats only partially true, there was a discussion about it here on SO; the standart only states that certain operations can require the element type to be MoveAssignable (c++11), it does however not state that a `std::vector` with a type not being MoveAssignable cannot be instantiated. Im not sure about this but I guess that implementation dependent.

Comment: @Paranaix So, for certain values of "doesn't allow it"... ;-) But I figure even implementation-defined behaviour would be silly to rely on, especially when it adds no value (AFAIK you can't mutate the elements anyway when the container itself is `const`).

Comment: @delnan Also see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4091ca36fad2a944 and compare with: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf68af09cc00dabc

Comment: @delnan I totally agree with you, but thats another story ^^

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Just quoting myself "2) if you can, you cant modify it in any way"

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case. Declare the parameter type based on the actual types your program uses - `const vector<string>&` is `const` transitive to include its contained strings. That is to say, `const vector<string>&` does not return mutable references to its `string`s.

Specifically, `const vector<const string>&` would be a very rare occurrence (i.e. nonexistent in many codebases) and would typically be painful and/or costly to convert to. Use it only where the inputs do not require conversion (e.g. from `std::vector<std::string>`).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments `const vector<const string>&` will likely not compile and if it does it will produce alot of other problems.

If you however really have to gurantee constness you could go with: `const vector<const string*>&`

Or: `const vector<shared_ptr<const string>>&`